# How to convert structured text to a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

Input:

```
5;IT=G45;NA=Goalscorers;SY=mgt;ST=#ST#F89096020#45;DO=1;OT=1;PD=#AC#B1#C1#D8#E8909#;OM=1;|
MA;SY=dq;NA=Each-way 1/3 Unlimited Places on First Goalscorers;|
MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA= ;FI=89096020;SY=dd;PY=da;OM=1;|
PA;ID=PC768184772;IT=89096020-768184772;NA=Krzysztof Piatek ;|
PA;ID=PC768184755;IT=89096020-768184755;NA=Vedad Ibisevic ;|
PA;ID=PC768184774;IT=89096020-768184774;NA=Santos Matheus Cunha ;|
PA;ID=PC768184785;IT=89096020-768184785;NA=Sebastian Andersson ;|
PA;ID=PC768184790;IT=89096020-768184790;NA=Anthony Ujah ;|
PA;ID=PC768184771;IT=89096020-768184771;NA=Dodi Lukebakio ;|
MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=First;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184772;IT=89096020-768184772;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184755;IT=89096020-768184755;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184774;IT=89096020-768184774;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184785;IT=89096020-768184785;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184790;IT=89096020-768184790;OD=ikwj;|
PA;ID=768184771;IT=89096020-768184771;OD=ikwj;|
MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=Last;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184816;IT=89096020-768184816;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184799;IT=89096020-768184799;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184818;IT=89096020-768184818;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184829;IT=89096020-768184829;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184834;IT=89096020-768184834;OD=ikwj;|
PA;ID=768184815;IT=89096020-768184815;OD=ikwj;|
MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=Anytime;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184862;IT=89096020-768184862;OD=iiw`;|
PA;ID=768184845;IT=89096020-768184845;OD=iiw`;|
PA;ID=768184864;IT=89096020-768184864;OD=owl;|
PA;ID=768184875;IT=89096020-768184875;OD=owl;|
PA;ID=768184880;IT=89096020-768184880;OD=jwi;|
PA;ID=768184861;IT=89096020-768184861;OD=jwi
```

Where lines:

```
PA;ID=PC768184772;IT=89096020-768184772;NA=Krzysztof Piatek ;|
PA;ID=PC768184755;IT=89096020-768184755;NA=Vedad Ibisevic ;|
PA;ID=PC768184774;IT=89096020-768184774;NA=Santos Matheus Cunha ;|
PA;ID=PC768184785;IT=89096020-768184785;NA=Sebastian Andersson ;|
PA;ID=PC768184790;IT=89096020-768184790;NA=Anthony Ujah ;|
PA;ID=PC768184771;IT=89096020-768184771;NA=Dodi Lukebakio ;|
```

And columns:

```
MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=First;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184772;IT=89096020-768184772;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184755;IT=89096020-768184755;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184774;IT=89096020-768184774;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184785;IT=89096020-768184785;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184790;IT=89096020-768184790;OD=ikwj;|
PA;ID=768184771;IT=89096020-768184771;OD=ikwj;|

MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=Last;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184816;IT=89096020-768184816;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184799;IT=89096020-768184799;OD=awj;|
PA;ID=768184818;IT=89096020-768184818;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184829;IT=89096020-768184829;OD=iiwj;|
PA;ID=768184834;IT=89096020-768184834;OD=ikwj;|
PA;ID=768184815;IT=89096020-768184815;OD=ikwj;|

MA;ID=M45;IT=M45;NA=Anytime;FI=89096020;SY=de;PY=_d;OM=1;|
PA;ID=768184862;IT=89096020-768184862;OD=iiw`;|
PA;ID=768184845;IT=89096020-768184845;OD=iiw`;|
PA;ID=768184864;IT=89096020-768184864;OD=owl;|
PA;ID=768184875;IT=89096020-768184875;OD=owl;|
PA;ID=768184880;IT=89096020-768184880;OD=jwi;|
PA;ID=768184861;IT=89096020-768184861;OD=jwi
```

Initially, there are no line breaks in the text, I made them just for clarity.

Expected outp:

```py
result_dict = {
    'Goalscorers': [
        {'ID': '768184772', 'IT': '89096020-768184772', 'OD': 'awj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Krzysztof Piatek '},
        {'ID': '768184755', 'IT': '89096020-768184755', 'OD': 'awj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Vedad Ibisevic '},
        {'ID': '768184774', 'IT': '89096020-768184774', 'OD': 'iiwj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Santos Matheus Cunha '},
        {'ID': '768184785', 'IT': '89096020-768184785', 'OD': 'iiwj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Sebastian Andersson '},
        {'ID': '768184790', 'IT': '89096020-768184790', 'OD': 'ikwj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Anthony Ujah '},
        {'ID': '768184771', 'IT': '89096020-768184771', 'OD': 'ikwj', 'COLUMN': 'First', 'LINE': 'Dodi Lukebakio '},
        {'ID': '768184816', 'IT': '89096020-768184816', 'OD': 'awj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Krzysztof Piatek '},
        {'ID': '768184799', 'IT': '89096020-768184799', 'OD': 'awj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Vedad Ibisevic '},
        {'ID': '768184818', 'IT': '89096020-768184818', 'OD': 'iiwj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Santos Matheus Cunha '},
        {'ID': '768184829', 'IT': '89096020-768184829', 'OD': 'iiwj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Sebastian Andersson '},
        {'ID': '768184834', 'IT': '89096020-768184834', 'OD': 'ikwj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Anthony Ujah '},
        {'ID': '768184815', 'IT': '89096020-768184815', 'OD': 'ikwj', 'COLUMN': 'Last', 'LINE': 'Dodi Lukebakio '},
        {'ID': '768184862', 'IT': '89096020-768184862', 'OD': 'iiw`', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Krzysztof Piatek '},
        {'ID': '768184845', 'IT': '89096020-768184845', 'OD': 'iiw`', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Vedad Ibisevic '},
        {'ID': '768184864', 'IT': '89096020-768184864', 'OD': 'owl', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Santos Matheus Cunha '},
        {'ID': '768184875', 'IT': '89096020-768184875', 'OD': 'owl', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Sebastian Andersson '},
        {'ID': '768184880', 'IT': '89096020-768184880', 'OD': 'jwi', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Anthony Ujah '},
        {'ID': '768184861', 'IT': '89096020-768184861', 'OD': 'jwi', 'COLUMN': 'Anytime', 'LINE': 'Dodi Lukebakio '},
    ]
}
```

My attempt to solve this is:

```py
line_keys = ('PA;', 'ID=', 'IT=', 'NA=')
column_keys = ('MA;', 'ID=', 'IT=', 'FI=', 'NA=')
bet_keys = ('PA;', 'ID=', 'IT=', 'OD=')


def parse_table_bet_template(prematch_data: dict, block: str):
    block_title = re.search(r'IT=.+?;NA=(.+?);', block).group(1)
    if block_title not in prematch_data.keys():
        prematch_data[block_title] = list()
    lines, line_index = dict(), 0
    for element in block.split('|'):
        if all((key in element for key in line_keys)):
            line_name = re.search(r'NA=(.+?)(;|$)', element).group(1)
            lines[line_index] = line_name
            line_index += 1
    block_list = block.split('|')
    column_name = None
    for index, items in enumerate(zip(block_list, block_list[1:])):
        previous, current = items[0], items[1]
        bet = dict()
        if (all((key in previous for key in column_keys)) and
            all((key in current for key in bet_keys))):
            column_name = re.search(r'IT=.+?;NA=(.+?);', block).group(1)
        if all((key in current for key in bet_keys)):
            for opt in element.split(';'):
                if len(opt.split('=')) >= 2:
                    key, value = opt[:2], opt[3:]
                    bet[key] = value
            bet['COLUMN'] = column_name
            bet['LINE'] = lines[index]
            prematch_data[block_title].append(bet)


prematch_data = dict()
parse_table_bet_template(prematch_data=prematch_data, block=text)
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     27 
     28 prematch_data = dict()
---> 29 parse_table_bet_template(prematch_data=prematch_data, block=text)

 in parse_table_bet_template(prematch_data, block)
     23                     bet[key] = value
     24             bet['COLUMN'] = column_name
---> 25             bet['LINE'] = lines[index]
     26             prematch_data[block_title].append(bet)
     27 

KeyError: 9
```

First, with a regex, I find the title for the whole block.

Further in the loop, I find the names of all the lines in the table and create a dictionary, where the key is the index (line position) and the value is the name of the line.

Next, I divide all the blocks into a list and start iterating it 2 lines at a time, I need to find the lines where the current line is the line with bets and the last line is the line with the column name, then I save the column name and continue to iterate further.

But at the time of writing the question, I realized that I iterate the entire block and the index goes beyond the lines, but I don’t know how to correctly split this block.

Comment: Can you clarify how your input translates to the expected output? How is the ``COLUMN`` entry deduced?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry for this, I updated my question, I hope now it’s clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in this way, I really do not think that this is the most pythonic way:

```py
def parse_table_bet_template(prematch_data: dict, block: str):
    block_title = re.search(r'IT=.+?;NA=(.+?);', block).group(1)
    if block_title not in prematch_data.keys():
        prematch_data[block_title] = list()
    lines, line_index = dict(), 0
    for element in block.split('|'):
        if all((key in element for key in line_keys)):
            line_name = re.search(r'NA=(.+?)(;|$)', element).group(1)
            lines[line_index] = line_name
            line_index += 1
    block_list = block.split('|')
    column_name = None
    line_index = 0
    for previous, current in zip(block_list, block_list[1:]):
        bet = dict()
        if (all((key in previous for key in column_keys)) and
            all((key in current for key in bet_keys))):
            column_name = re.search(r'IT=.+?;NA=(.+?);', previous).group(1)
            line_index = 0
        if all((key in current for key in bet_keys)):
            for opt in current.split(';'):
                if len(opt.split('=')) >= 2:
                    key, value = opt[:2], opt[3:]
                    bet[key] = value
            bet['COLUMN'] = column_name
            bet['LINE'] = lines[line_index]
            line_index += 1
            prematch_data[block_title].append(bet)
```